# Use UFormat to get unix time

Tags: powershell

I can use following to append a date to a text:

```
"Foo {0:G} Foo" -f (date)     #returns "Foo 2009-12-07 15:34:16 Foo"
```

But I want the time in Unix format.
I can get it by `date -UFormat %s`, but can I use the same syntax?

When I use `-UFormat %s` I get *1260199855,65625*, how do I remove the decimal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just cast the result to an int like so:

```
PS> [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat %s))
1260172909

PS> "Foo {0:G} Foo" -f [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat %s))
Foo 1260172997 Foo
```

Using the Parse method means the string is parsed "culture aware" such that the appropriate decimal separator character is recognized for the current culture.  If you just cast directly, PowerShell uses the invariant culture which causes problems for any culture where decimal sep char is not a period.

Comment: If I use [int](get-date -UFormat %s), I get 
Cannot convert value "123456789,12345" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Apparently, PowerShell uses invariant culture when coercing from a string to a number which means only a period is recognized as the decimal separator character.  I've updated the answer to accomodate.

Comment: Downvote because this has the wrong timezone. The number you get is not a unix timestamp.

Comment: Unfortunately powershell 5.1 outputs this in local time, NOT utc.

Answer (score 27):

```
[int](Get-Date -UFormat %s -Millisecond 0)
```

Comment: This is the better answer for PS3.0+.

Comment: Really, if you looking for that format, what the same like in php DateTimeInterface::getTimestamp what is Unix timestamp, only this is the right answer on this page!

Comment: This is not unixtime. It uses your timezone

Comment: Unix time is UTC, but this uses your local timezone and gives the wrong result

Answer (score 23):

Here's how I do it:

```
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$UnixTimeStamp = [System.Math]::Truncate((Get-Date -Date $DateTime -UFormat %s))
```

Comment: This is the only answer that calculates an actual Unix time stamp (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**).
Note that since .NET 4.6 there is a dedicated method for it: `([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date)).ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Comment: `$UnixTimeStamp` will have way too many digits in it. The suggestion by @Anton corrects the problem.

Comment: @argonym Can be abbreviated to `[DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` ;-)

Comment: Genius @NicolasMelay - worked perfectly for me. Kudos to Jon Bonner for posting correct answer and argonym for pointing out that it was the only answer that generated actual unix time stamp - helped me as I couldn't work out why the code from the accepted answer wasn't working for me

Answer (score 6):

I did this, rounded up

```
[System.Math]::Round((date -UFormat %s),0)
```

Comment: An obvious solution when you see it:-)

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
(Get-Date -UFormat %s) -Replace("[,\.]\d*", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just truncate the decimal:

```
(date -UFormat %s).split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be in UTC.  This should be good for embedding in Discord.  See https://www.unixtimestamp.com  "-uformat %s" does NOT convert to UTC in powershell 5.1 (but powershell 7 does).  Only one other answer takes this into account, and not the accepted answer.

```
$unixtime = get-date '12/28/22 10pm' | % ToUniversalTime | get-date -uformat %s
"<t:$unixtime>"

<t:1672282800>
```

Alternative for UTC unix time:

```
[datetimeoffset]'12/28/22 10pm' | % ToUnixTimeSeconds

1672282800
```